# is this the correct way of writing the exception in python?

Tags: python, function, class, exception

Is this the following code the correct way of writing the exception in Python?

```
class Calculator:
    def power(self,n,p):
        self.n=n
        self.p=p
        if self.n>=0 and self.p>=0:
            return self.n**self.p
        else:
            return ("n and p should be non-negative")


myCalculator=Calculator()
T=int(input())
for i in range(T):
    n,p = map(int, input().split())
    try:
        ans=myCalculator.power(n,p)
        print(ans)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the code not work? What exactly is the problem you want to solve.

Comment: You probably meant to raise an exception when either argument to `power` is negative, not return a string.

Comment: raise ValueError and except ValueError instead of Exception. It's more focused and won't capture different exceptions.

Comment: Sometimes you can also customize if no existing Exception looks appropriate by just defining a custom exception with `class YourException(Exception): pass`

Comment: Without more context, I'd give a pass to catching `Exception` instead of a more specific exception, since at least the exception is logged rather than being ignored altogether.

Comment: @chepner I meant raise ValueError("Your error message") if that's what you meant by being ignored.

Comment: @progmatico No, catching any exception beyond the expected `ValueError` (if that's what `power` does and should raise). Lots of people write code like `except Except: pass`, then ask for help debugging the problems that occur later due to ignoring the exception.

Comment: @chepner, your comment means (had trouble with the wording, sorry) ValueError should be catched but catching Exception is also acceptable, given it is printed to the screen, if it happens to be a different Exception. If so maybe you should change the except in your answer to ValueError (as being "more right" than acceptable?

Comment: Getting into which exceptions to catch and why would make for a long answer that is only tangentially related to the question. I'm content to leave my answer as-is.

Comment: That's ok. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply returning a string from `power` where you probably want to raise an exception. Also, you should check `n` and `p` *before* you modify the object. (I won't go further into why `power` is setting attributes.)

```
class Calculator:
    def power(self, n, p):
        if n < 0 or p < 0:
            raise ValueError("Both arguments should be non-negative")
        self.n = n
        self.p = p
        return self.n ** self.p

myCalculator = Calculator()
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    n, p = map(int, input().split())
    try:
        ans = myCalculator.power(n,p)
        print(ans)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```